# Should/can I pass JSX components that do not render?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I've seen in multiple libraries built on React now, that passing JSX components for defining functionalities, but not immediate HTML output, seems to be widely accepted.

For example (maybe a bad one) react-router defines routes using JSX components, though those routes rather define a configuration instead of only rendering.

I have the situation that I want to attach a tree of actions (like sub menus) to multiple types of components. There is a menu component that outputs a button with a context menu, but I also have to pass the same set of actions to a different trigger, that, maybe, renders a whole different set of elements to reflect those actions.

My idea is to create a JSX component that only defines the action with child actions and never renders directly, but is used by a parent component to iterate over them and even call callbacks on those actions.

How should I solve this? Or should I not use JSX but a different class definition? The idea to use JSX components derives from the fact that they're extremely comfortable to use, as instantiation is very short and keeps the instantiating classes code clean.

Last but not least: How can I even achieve this? I am not sure how to implement such a pattern, as calling methods like the callback on JSX components is not publicly available.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sounds like you want to write a higher order component.

Comment: You may want to look at Redux which can help you with clearly defining the possible actions.

Comment: Please Show a minimal Code example what you want at least some Pseudo Code